# Getting wireless working on (K)ubuntu 14.04, HP Pavilion

Tags: 14.04, wireless, kubuntu, hp-pavilion

After installing Kubuntu 14.04 on my new HP Pavilion laptop, I discovered that wireless was not working at all -- it just wasn't there.  I did not have that problem with later versions of Kubuntu, and my wired connection worked fine.

Comment: What wireless do you have?  In terminal `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`  Your answer doesn't make much sense as is.   Why would anyone need to install rtlwifi-new-dkms and a different kernel and where does rtlwifi-new-dkms come from, hanipouspilot PPA?

Answer (score 0):

After a great deal of web-searching and experimentation, I discovered a reasonably straightforward way of activating wireless that doesn't require much extra knowledge.

First, you need to install **rtlwifi-new-dkms** with

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
>
> sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms

Then you need to upgrade  your kernel from 4.4 to 4.8.  You'll find instructions at [Installing Kernel 4.8.17](http://linuxg.net/install-kernel-4-8-on-ubuntu/).

Or use these instructions copied from there:

```
Download the needed packages:

$ cd /tmp

$ wget \

kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.17/linux-headers-4.8.17-040817_4.8.17-040817.201701090438_all.deb \

kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.17/linux-headers-4.8.17-040817-generic_4.8.17-040817.201701090438_amd64.deb \

kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.8.17/linux-image-4.8.17-040817-generic_4.8.17-040817.201701090438_amd64.deb

Install the Kernel:

$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.8*.deb linux-image-4.8*.deb

Optional, remove the kernel:

$ sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-4.8* linux-image-4.8*
```

Then reboot, possibly twice.  When I did it I got a couple of errors but they didn't seem to affect anything.